# How do I access the "WindowedApplication" class in Actionscript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air, flash-builder

How do I access the "WindowedApplication" class in Actionscript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean the top level application of an AIR App?

In Flex 4, use [FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/FlexGlobals.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2).

In Flex 3 or before, use [Application.application](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#application)

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the top level of the application.

Comment: @Moshe then glad to help; you have your answer.  Be sure to accept it as correct.